# WinDbg .for loop

Tags: windbg

I am having trouble getting the WinDbg .for command to work.

I would like to dump an array of c++ structs.

`?? gpTranData->mpApplCodes[0]` works for a single entry but I would like to loop through n of these.

```
.for ($t0=0;$t0<(gpTranData->miApplCodeCount);$t0++){ ?? &gpTranData->mpApplCodes[$t0] }
```

sound logical to me but I get

```
Numeric expression missing from '>miApplCodeCount);$t0++){ ?? &gpTranData->m_pApplCodes[$t0] }'
```

Any ideas?

Scott

Comment: Check this: http://jumpdollar.blogspot.com/2014/09/windbg-for-command-for-looping.html

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use C++ operators to modify pseudo-register l-values in Windbg. You can use instead **r $t0=@$t0+1** . This will work as you want:

```
.for (r $t0=0;@$t0<@@c++(g_pTranData->m_iApplCodeCount);r $t0=@$t0+1){ ?? &g_pTranData->m_pApplCodes[@$t0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the masm evaluator is missing some data on your `gpTranData->miApplCodeCount` input. Wrap your expression with either @@c++() or @@().

Comment: .for (r $t0=0;@$t0<@@c++(g_pTranData->m_iApplCodeCount);@$t0++){ ?? &g_pTranData->m_pApplCodes[@$t0] } 

runs but does not iterate $t0